# How to prevent Python-mode from auto inserting "import"?

Tags: vim, python-mode, jedi-vim

I use [Python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) (pymode) in Vim. When I begin typing an import statement,

```
from foo import bar
```

Pymode auto inserts `import` such that I end up with

```
from foo import import bar
```

How can I prevent Pymode from auto inserting/completing `import`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this behaviour using Jedi-vim, specifcally the [smart_auto_mappings](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/doc/jedi-vim.txt#L498) feature which is enabled by default.

You can disable it by adding:

```
let g:jedi#smart_auto_mappings = 0
```

To your ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 1):

You may like to disable `python-mode` auto completion by putting `let g:pymode_rope_completion = 0` in your `~/.vimrc`